# Norm of a basis vector multiplied by a matrix

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Considering the standard basis of a vector space, if I multiply each of the basis vectors by a matrix M, then is it possible to show that all of them, i.e Mv (where v is a vector in the standard basis) have the same norm? And what conditions must the matrix satisfy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it‘s untrue, for example:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$
has euclidian Norm $\sqrt{2^2+1^2}$ while
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0\\1 \end{bmatrix}  = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$
has euclidian Norm $\sqrt{2}$.

What you want are orthogonal / unitary transformations. If you only consider the euclidian norm look at the orthogonal/unitary group O(n), U(n).
Unitary/orthogonal transformations keep the inner product the same:
$f: V \to W$ with vectorspaces V, W and inner products $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_V$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_W$ then it is an unitary transformation if:

$$\langle f(v),f(w) \rangle_W = \langle v,w\rangle_V \forall v,w \in V$$

Since every inner product induces a norm it follows that:

$$||f(v)||_W = ||v||_V \forall v \in V$$

Comment: How to prove that the norm is same for orthogonal transformations?

Comment: @birds_of_prey Every inner prdoduct induces a norm: if you have an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ then $||v|| := \sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle} is a norm (you can proof it by simply showing the axioms). If you take the standard inner product (dot product) it induces the euklidian norm. Now if your transformation keeps the inner product the same, it doesnt change the norm either (considering the induced norm)